# Requirements for hosting a PHP website on local PC Apache

Tags: apache, web-hosting, nameservers

1. I have a PC which has a static IP. (Windows XP OS)
2. I have a domain name purchased ex- ipower.com from GoDaddy
3. My PC has a WAMP server installed and the files of the website are in the root of the wamp www folder.

The thing I need to know is

1. how I can point my domain name to my static IP, and
2. is there any other hardware or software need for this task?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can point your domain to your IP address at Go Daddy.

To Access the Zone File Editor

1. Log in to your Account Manager.
2. Next to Domains, click Launch.
3. Do one of the following:
4. Click the domain name you want to update, and, in the DNS Manager section, click Launch.
5. In the A (Host) section, click the A record you want to edit.
6. Edit any of the following fields:

   Host — Enter the host name the A record links to. Type @ to map the record directly to your domain name, including the www.
   Points to — Enter the IP address your domain name uses for this host record.
   TTL — Select how long the server should cache the information.
7. Click Save Zone File, and then click OK.

DNS changes can take 24-48 hours to propagate.  Once this is done and the time has passed for propagation the domain will be pointed to your WAMP setup.  You will just need to setup Apache. You may also need to make sure your firewall allows for port 80.